# shear and normal stresses

Tags: fluid-dynamics

When we talk about shear stresses in a fluid, we find that the shear stress is given by $$\tau_{xy} = \mu(\partial_y u + \partial_x v) = \tau_{yx}$$ This relation we get when only looking at one side of our fluid-"cube". Now, in order to take into account the opposite side we assume that the fluid element is so small that the shear stress is constant, leading to the average $$\tau_{xy} = \frac{1}{2}2\mu(\partial_y u + \partial_x v) = \mu(\partial_y u + \partial_x v) = \tau_{yx}$$ Applying the same logic to the normal stresses gives me $$\tau_{xx} = \frac{1}{2}\mu(\partial_x u + \partial_x u) = \mu(\partial_x u)$$ However, in my textbook (White) it is given as 
$$\tau_{xx} = 2\mu(\partial_x u)$$ Where does this extra factor of 2 come from in the normal stress?

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the stress tensor is (in Einstein summation notation):

$$ \tau_{ij} = \mu \left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \right)$$

So, if you look at $\tau_{ii}$, you get $2\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}$. That's really where the factors come from, not from "averaging" over any fluid element or anything like that. It's just due to the symmetry of the tensor.

Comment: So you are adding the angular deformation for adjacent sides in $\tau_{ij}$, but in $\tau_{ii}$ you are adding *opposite* sides. Why is that? IMO, seeing as there are no adjacent sides to $\tau_{ii}$, it should merely be $\partial u_i/\partial x_i$

Comment: I'm not adding any sides in anything. This is the definition of the stress tensor *on each face*. So if you wanted to take the average for some reason, you would get $1/2 (2*\tau_{ij})$ for all $i,j$ which gives you the correct answer also. You're confusing two different things -- the balance of the stress tensor across a differential fluid element, and the definition of the stress tensor.